# Visual Studio Blue Eye Strike-through meaning

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am writing tests in Visual Studio 2017 and sometimes I see the following icon [image: Strange icon] on the left of the test method signature. What does this icon mean? The black and white circle is there all of the time, but the blue eye with a strike-through only shows up occasionally. It may or may not be relevant but I am using ReSharper Ultimate as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [ReSharper Action Indicators and Action List](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Actions_List.html), that icon is a ReSharper icon. The circle means unit test; the circle with the blue eye with a bar means "the unit test was ignored during the last execution".